# Ember Data 1.0.0: record.rollback() clears out all attributes - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/HKHEJ/2/

I am converting from Ember data 0.13 to 1.0.0 beta.  In previous versions you could use transaction.rollback() to revert any changes made in a model (and not yet saved).

In 1.0.0 you can use record.rollback().  The problem I have is that all attributes are cleared at that moment ...

```
 cancel: function () {
      var author = this.get('model');
      author.rollback();
    },
```

Scenario in JSFiddle: click on a name, change the text in one of the textfields, then click "Revert changes".  All fields are cleared, except the id.

Is this a known issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is a known issue, it was fixed in commit [Add support for rollback](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/09df3c3955a46f5b5cd58a4c1b802e316e105c91)

I updated your jsfiddle to use [ember-data-latest](http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js) and rollback now works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/HKHEJ/2/

```
  author.rollback();
```

Comment: Great ! Will immediately download latest master and implement in my code.  Have similar issues with rollback of deleted record, but perhaps these are also solved now ...  if not, then I post another JSFiddle.